# How to clear ThreadContext/MDC in ALL Spring scheduled jobs?

Tags: spring

Is there any way to clear ThreadContext/MDC in ALL Spring scheduled jobs automatically?  I know I can clear manually in each one.

What's I'm looking for is something like the filter to clear it in all HTTP requests, like this:

```
public class LogMeThreadContextFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        ThreadContext.clearAll();
    }
}
```

Is there something similar for methods annotated like this?:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7,15,23 * * *")
public void myMethod() {
  ThreadContext.put("myThing", "myValue"
```

}

Thanks!!!

Comment: `ThreadContext.clearAll` doesn't do what you think it does. It will only clear the things that are set in the `ThreadContext` (or MDC for Log4j2, it doesn't clear stuff on other threads). Also `clearAll` seems dangerous to me, as it can clear values that are set in an earlier stage to early. My rule of thumb, remove the stuff in the place where you set it (or at the end). In your method you can add a `finally` which would clear the value. Or you could use a `TaskDecorator` which you can use to wrap a task (the method execution) and clear it in there.